# Android - Volley - Request GET using headers not working

Tags: android, android-volley

I'm trying to request a server. It's working when I request from chrome extension. However it's not working using Volley. This is the code:

```
public void login(final String email, final String password) {
    String url = BASE_URL + "login";
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(mContext);
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, this, this) {
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
            headers.put("email", email);
            headers.put("password", password);
            return headers;
        }
    };
    queue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

Error listener is being triggered instead of the Success listener.
Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

try adding this into your code

```
            try {
                    headers.putAll(super.getHeaders());
                } catch (AuthFailureError authFailureError) {
                    authFailureError.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Code will be something like below

```
 public void login(final String email, final String password) {
    String url = BASE_URL + "login";
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(mContext);
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, this, this) {
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
            headers.put("email", email);
            headers.put("password", password);

                try {
                        headers.putAll(super.getHeaders());
                    } catch (AuthFailureError authFailureError) {
                        authFailureError.printStackTrace();
                    }
            return headers;
        }
    };
    queue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

Comment: Not worked... Same problem... onErrorResponse is being triggered.